# Check for Textboxes with String value

Tags: vb.net, textbox, foreach, msgbox

All I want to do is to check for textboxes with string value if yes then the message box will appear saying (use number).

```
    For Each t In Me.Controls
        If TextBox1.Text = (String) Then
            MsgBox("Please Use Number")
            Exit Sub
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I *assume* that since you're using `MsgBox`, you're building a WinForms application, but it would be clearer if you add an appropriate tag. There are many different controls in the .NET framework, parts of different technology stacks, where each one is named `TextBox`. The best way to approach the problem is likely different for each one.

Comment: This is a statement not a question... Anyway, 1. You need to typecast t to a textbox. 2. TextBox1.Text should be <typecastedTextbox variable>.Text. 3. if statement should be checked if it is a number, not a string. It will always be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error-message i assume that you want to validate that the user entered a numerical value. Then you can either use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx#Y0) or [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w0x0ctx.aspx) or simply enumerate all chars and check if they are digits:

```
For Each txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of textBox)()
    Dim allDigit = txt.Text.Trim.Length <> 0 AndAlso _
            txt.Text.All(Function(chr) Char.IsDigit(chr))
    If Not allDigit Then
        MsgBox("Please Use Number")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

With `Int32.TryParse`:

```
Dim intVal As Int32
Dim isInteger As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, intVal)
```

(assuming also that you want to validate all TextBoxes on your form)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (c) Is TextBox Then
        If Not IsNumeric(c.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Not a number")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to validate whether or not textbox contains number.

Eg.

```
Dim regNumber As New Regex("^\d{1,10}$")
regNumber.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text)
```